# Package hyperref spoils vertical spacing between displayed math and consecutive environment

Tags: spacing, hyperref

When the `hyperref` package is used, the vertical space is spoiled in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\newtheorem{rk}{Remark}
\begin{document}
Consider this:
\[
a=b
\]
\begin{rk}
Too much space above if hyperref line is uncommented!
\end{rk}
\end{document}
```

What would be a proper way to correct this, without dropping `hyperref`?

Comment: Imho it is a variant of an already reported bug and I added a comment there: https://github.com/ho-tex/hyperref/issues/11. If you load amsthm the spacing will be ok.

Comment: Thanks, you're right! But if you use thmtools too, as I do in my original file, then the problem returns...

Comment: Well the problem is complicated. hyperref inserts anchors for the links and this change spacing. If you have more failing examples you should add them to the bug report.

Comment: Just realized that loading thmtools *before* amsthm solves this issue.